# highcharts : Use zoneAxis x AND zoneAxis y

Tags: highcharts

It is possible use zoneAxis x AND zoneAxis y?

I want use

```
zones: [{
   value: 0,
   color: '#f7a35c'
}, {
   value: 10,
   color: '#7cb5ec'
}, {
   color: '#90ed7d'
}]
```

AND

```
zoneAxis: 'x',
zones: [{
    value: 8
}, {
    dashStyle: 'dot'
}]
```

in One Chart.

Can you help me ?

Comment: Could you please edit your question with a working fiddle of your chart?

Comment: I want Combine http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/series/color-zones-dashstyle-dot/ AND http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/series/color-zones-simple/

Comment: No, you cannot use both. However, you could use zones on x axis that will look like zones on y axis - demo: http://jsfiddle.net/h41uv2kk/